# send radio button value and the text with radio button to php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to send radio button value with radio button text to php.

I'm able to send radio button value, i want to send the text after the radio button too without changing the checkbox information, however i cannot send the text to php.

```
<input name="list" type="checkbox" value="15.00" />Shirt
<input name="list" type="checkbox" value="19.00" />Trousers
<input name="list" type="checkbox" value="16.00" />Shorts
<input name="list" type="checkbox" value="14.50" />Skirt
```

I'm trying to send the following text(s);

Shirt,
Trousers,
Shorts,
Skirt.

When each checkbox is selected i want to send the text to php too.

Comment: You're aware those are not radio buttons right? so your code is inconsistent with your question...

Comment: i made a mistake i meant checkbox**

Comment: Alright then you need to remember checkbox cannot have the same name...like that list list list

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want this...

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['li1'])){  echo $_POST['li1']." Shirt ";  }
    if(isset($_POST['li2'])){  echo $_POST['li2']." Trousers ";  }
    if(isset($_POST['li3'])){  echo $_POST['li3']." Shorts ";  }
    if(isset($_POST['li4'])){  echo $_POST['li4']." Skirt ";  }

?>
```

But your html code should be like

```
<input name="li1" type="checkbox" value="15.00" />Shirt
<input name="li2" type="checkbox" value="19.00" />Trousers
<input name="li3" type="checkbox" value="16.00" />Shorts
<input name="li4" type="checkbox" value="14.50" />Skirt
```

You cannot use the same name for inputs unless

```
   (1) You're trying to create an array from the inputs
or (2) Your input is a radio button or a select > option
```